# How to Add My Custom C++ Executable in Mac App Contents/MacOS Folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to add a C++ Executable file to my App's MacOS Folder. The Executable file needs no plist or anything to run. It runs without any other files support. So i tried adding this file to my Xcode project , when i build my app, the binary resulted in Resources Folder.

The App is running fine, but i want the executable to be in Contents/MacOS folder. How to achieve this ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 'copy file' phase in your app's target.

Comment: It's also resulting in Resources Folder

Comment: There's a `Destination` option in Copy File phase where you can specify custom destination.

Comment: Thanks, i had to Choose Executables as Destination in Xcode to get the  Binary in Contents/MacOS folder.